# Catching errors generated in Promises within Promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, bluebird

Is it possible to have errors bubble up in Promises?

See the code below for reference, I'd like to get `promise1.catch` to catch the error generated in `promise2` (which current does not work with this code):

```
function test() {
    var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve1) {
        var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve2) {
            throw new Error('Error in promise2!');
        });

        promise2.catch(function(error2) {
            console.log('Caught at error2', error2);
        });
    });

    promise1.catch(function(error1) {
        console.log('Caught at error1', error1);
    });
}

test();
```

Comment: Just don't nest `Promise` constructors. There's absolutely zero reason to do so. What do you try to achieve?

Comment: Apart from that, do re-`throw error2` in the catch handler, and `resolve1()` the outer promise with it.

Answer (score 7):

#### Yes!!

Error propagation in promises is one of its strongest suits. It acts exactly like in synchronous code.

```
try { 
    throw new Error("Hello");
} catch (e){
    console.log('Caught here, when you catch an error it is handled');
}
```

Is very similar to:

```
Promise.try(function(){
    throw new Error("Hello");
}).catch(function(e){
    console.log('Caught here, when you catch an error it is handled');
});
```

Just like in sequential code, if you want to do some logic to the error but not mark it as handled - you rethrow it:

```
try { 
   throw new Error("Hello");
} catch (e){
    console.log('Caught here, when you catch an error it is handled');
    throw e; // mark the code as in exceptional state
}
```

Which becomes:

```
var p = Promise.try(function(){
   throw new Error("Hello");
}).catch(function(e){
    console.log('Caught here, when you catch an error it is handled');
    throw e; // mark the promise as still rejected, after handling it.
});

p.catch(function(e){
     // handle the exception
});
```

Note that in Bluebird you can have typed and conditional catches, so if all you're doing is an `if` on the type or contents of the promise to decide whether or not to handle it - you can save that.

```
var p = Promise.try(function(){
   throw new IOError("Hello");
}).catch(IOError, function(e){
    console.log('Only handle IOError, do not handle syntax errors');
});
```

You can also use `.error` to handle `OperationalError`s which originate in promisified APIs. In general `OperationalError` signifies an error you can recover from (vs a programmer error). For example:

```
var p = Promise.try(function(){
   throw new Promise.OperationalError("Lol");
}).error(function(e){
    console.log('Only handle operational errors');
});
```

This has the advantage of not silencing `TypeError`s or syntax errors in your code, which can be annoying in JavaScript.