# Javascript Exceptions are hidden in Promises. How can I display them without catch?

Tags: javascript, exception, promise, es6-promise

**Edit:**

Promises do not hide exceptions, as was pointed out by the excellent (accepted) answer. I want to elaborate on how exceptions in promises were invisible:

I was working on a project that used a propriatary library to make ajax calls. Now in case something in the callback of the ajax-call went wrong an exception would be thrown. This exception would then trigger the reject() to be called, which was then silently discarded. In fact the exceptions were not hidden, but actively disposed of further down the code in an empty error-callback. This ultimatly led to a situation where it was very difficult to even recognize that an error had occured.

---

**Here the original question:**

I know that I can add a catch-block to all my promises and console.log the error there. In my usecase I need to catch the exceptions at a higher level up the call-stack.

http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/

Here in another question on SO, the accepted answer also proposes catch-blocks:

[Catching errors generated in Promises within Promises in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035019/catching-errors-generated-in-promises-within-promises-in-javascript)

Comment: That article you read is over two years old. Promises are in no way *silently* swallowing exceptions any more.

Comment: Yes, you definitely should `.catch()` and handle *any* errors in your asynchronous programs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Javascript silently swallows Exceptions that are thrown within a Promise.

No, it doesn't. An exception thrown in a promise executor (the function you pass `new Promise`) or a `then`/`catch` handler is used as the value of the rejection of the promise. Any decent implementation will also log a console error if you have unhandled rejections. For instance, try this in a recent version of Chrome or Firefox:

```js
new Promise(() => { throw new Error("Unhandled"); })
```

In the console you'll find:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unhandled
    at Promise (js:13)
    at new Promise ()
    at js:13
```

Soon, NodeJS will start terminating the process on unhandled rejections just like unhandled exceptions. Because rejections *are* exceptions.

> I do not want to add a catch-block to all my promises.

You don't have to. The rule of promises is you either *return* the promise or handle rejections from it; almost never both. (You'd do both only rarely, such as when you're "wrapping" the error that occurred to make it more high-level.) So you only need a `catch` on promises that you don't propagate to the caller. Best practice is to propagate to the highest level you can and then handle them there. Most of the time you don't write a `catch` because you're propagating the promise.

> Can I monkey-patch (or else) the native Promises in such a way that they stop hiding my exceptions?

Well, again, they don't. You can replace `Promise` and `Promise.prototype.then` so they report exceptions to the console, but you'll end up reporting things that are *handled* by subsequent handlers and shouldn't be reported. For example:

```js
// NOT RECOMMENDED
const RealPromise = Promise;
Promise = class Promise extends RealPromise {
  constructor(executor) {
    super((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        executor(resolve, reject);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  }
  
  then(onResolved, onRejected) {
    return super.then(val => {
      try {
        return onResolved(val);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
        throw e;
      }
    }, onRejected);
  }
};

new Promise(() => {
  throw new Error("Handled");
}).catch(e => {
  console.log("But I handled it!");
});
```

...but it wouldn't be a good idea, as you can see.

If you follow the propagate-or-handle rule, you should be fine with built-in promises.

---

It's also probably worth noting `async`/`await` syntax, which are new as of ES2017: When using `async`/`await`, promise rejection values are used as exceptions, closing the circle:

```js
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(reject, 500, "Failed");
  });
}
(async () => {
  try {
    await foo();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Got error: ", e);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

In browsers, you can listen to the [`unhandledrejection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unhandledrejection) event that is emitted for uncaught rejected promises:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // the reject value is available as event.reason
  console.error("Promise was rejected with reason:", event.reason);
});


Promise.reject("something");
```

This applies both to native promises and some Promise libraries (such as [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error-management-configuration.html)).