# Why is nodejs silently failing on an undeclared variable?

Tags: node.js, debugging

Why is nodejs silently failing on an undeclared variable? It doesn't say anything, no stack trace, etc. This is the worst situation for debugging.

How do I get it to be noisier like any other language?

This is a little command-line utility written in nodejs. It's not a web app like most people are making. I'm fine with that. It's working as expected and I'm happily porting code over and everything works nice except when I make a typo and then it silently fails.

```
// Typo: should be var or const foo but I missed it and I want nodejs  to error about it like any other language
foo = func();
```

I got a hint somewhere that promises are silencing errors like this. If so, why, and is there a workaround, preferably to make it die loudly.

Thanks

Comment: It's not failing because it shouldn't

Comment: This is completely legal in JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoot me. I missed logging the result of a promise rejection higher up. Once I put that in I started seeing the error and stack trace which was very helpful.

If I remember to log all rejection errors this will be fine.

The magic bit is that promises will use exceptions and send them to the rejection handler as the result object automatically.

This question+answer was helpful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46512164/3727869

Comment: Yep, when you fail to log or handle promise rejections, you are setting yourself up to be "silently eating" errors which is why node.js warns you about doing that.  It's like having a `try/catch` for synchronous exceptions with an empty catch as in:  `catch() { /* do nothing */}`.